# Delete parent directory and all child files then redirect

Tags: php, html

I have a page structure like this:

```
domain.com/index.php
domain.com/setup/index.php
domain.com/setup/setup.php
```

There's a form on the page `/setup/index.php` that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="finishSubmit" value="Finish" />
</form>
```

When that form is submitted, I want the directory `/setup/` to be deleted, along with it's children `index.php` and `setup.php`. After that, I need it to redirect to `domain.com/index.php`

I tried using `rmdir` like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['finishSubmit'])) {
  rmdir('../setup');
  header ('location: ../');
}
```

Either I'm using it wrong or I'm getting the paths wrong, but it's not working. What is the correct way to do this?

**NOTE:** I need to use relative paths such as above because I won't know the domain name.

Comment: Do you get any errors or does the remove just not happen? Are you redirected correctly?

Comment: does your script have the right permissions?

Comment: `rmdir()` requires the directory to be empty. You're better off iterating through the folder and deleting the files, then delete the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rmdir()` requires the directory to be empty. You can use this function to delete the files in the folder, then remove the folder after.

```
<?PHP
function delete_files($target) {
    if(is_dir($target)){
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK );
        foreach( $files as $file )
        {
            delete_files( $file );      
        }
        rmdir( $target );
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The function looks good but since I know there will only be those 2 files in the directory, I can just use unlink for both of them.

Comment: Nice use of the `glob()` function.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, you can just `unlink()` the files and then `rmdir()` the folder.

Comment: In this example, what would happen if a particular file could not be deleted, would the function quit in mid-route or just leave a partial directory structure with a single file?

Comment: It would quit mid-execution and halt on the file it tried to delete, leaving the folder structure as is.

Comment: How would I select the current directory to irate through and delete? I've tried `__DIR__` but that won't do it.

Comment: Try stepping down the directory and deleting the folder. `delete_files('../setup');`

Comment: Ah sweet, got it working now! Cheers for your help. I used your function in the end to make sure any extra files that might be generated in that directory are deleted too.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP `rmdir` function only works for empty directories.

You would need to delete the `index.php` file and an other files first before removing the directory.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: Ah right! I must have missed that first bit in the manual. Thanks.